# Alternatives to HUD

Tags: software-rec, unity

Are there alternatives to [HUD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/HUD) (from unity) which work together with different window managers (especially with tiling WM's)?

Answer (score 0):

Well...I don't use GNOME or Unity, but this is kind of similar than KRunner in KDE (which I prefer). They are both called with `ALT` + `F2` shortcut and basically do the same thing, except KRunner is a lot more sleek :P

Comment: Thanks. It seems that one has to add appmenu-runner. I will try it to make it work independently of kde for example in xmonad...